# When printing the contents of my defaultdict, why do I get inconsistent spacing?

Tags: python, printing, pydev, defaultdict

This is what it looks like:

[image: weird]

What I have is a defaultdic of my results:

```
results=defaultdict(list)
```

Each entry in a list is an object that contains the original word (originalWord), its alphabetized version (azWord), and the length of the word (wLength).

I then print the results as follows:

```
for length in results:
    print (length, [t.originalWord for t in results[length]])
```

Why do I get newlines for the non-existent entries of 15 and 16 (I don't have words of such length, as it seems), but not for entries 24 through 44?

Edit: I'd like to note that all originalWord strings were stripped using .strip('\r\n')

Edit 2: I actually do have words of length 15 and 15 but it's not printing those.

Edit 3: It's actually printing the lines... But in white font. Huh?

Comment: Beautiful, looks like sun rays.

Answer (score 0):

You have such data. You can notice a strange symbol on the next line after 14.

I am sure if you do `print(results[14])` you will understand why it's happening.

Comment: That is not a strange simple, it's just where I clicked with my cursor  when I screenshotted the results. See my edit.

Comment: Is this a screenshot from a text editor? Can you put a breakpoint before the loop `import pdb; prdb.set_trace()` and `print len(results[14]), results[14]`?

Comment: Hey, I already tried stepping through with the debugger. It actually does print stuff for 15 and 16, but the font is white/invisible. I can highlight it, copy/paste into notepad, and view the words. However, I don't see anything if I just highlight it in the console. I'm using PyDev in Eclipse.

Comment: This could be an Eclipse bug (line too long?), or the printed words can have some invisible control symbols inside

Comment: The only chars I have in the dictionary I'm reading are lowercase letters a-z. I looked closer and now I noticed it does visibly print the last few words in rows 15 and 16, but only at the end.

Comment: I think you should delete this question, as it's not a programming question

Comment: Where do you propose I ask this question, then? To me this looks like an issue with the way Python prints the contents of defaultdict.

Comment: It cannot be the default dict, as you do print a list from its values. It's about data stored in the list and where it is printed. Please check (via a Python code) that in `results[15]` and `results[16]` there are only letters in the strings.

Comment: This question is perfectly on-topic as it is about a programming tool misbehaving. No need to delete the post.